# Matlab GUI - how can I use handles in my own function?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am creating a simple GUI in Matlab, I have some buttons, static texts and my own function. How can I use:

```
set(handles.myStaticText, 'String', 'That works!');
```

in my function? When I use such a line in my function, I get the error:

Undefined variable "handles"

Comment: It sounds like there's no variable called `handles` defined in the scope of your function. In the default GUI functions that MATLAB generates, the `handles` variable is passed in as an argument. Without example code which demonstrates the error there's not much more I can say.

Comment: Maybe use "nested functions" so you can access the handles in all parts, instead of passing it in as an argument.

Comment: In my function I make some math calculations and I would like to display the result in a static text. I've got:

Comment: In my function I make some math calculations and I would like to display the result in a static text. I have got an "Edit Text" and "Push Button" to set an input data, my own function to make some calculations and "Static Text" to display the result. In my function I wanted to write that line set(handles.myStaticText, 'String', num2str(result)), but I have an error that I have written in the first comment.